# Changing Cloud SQL block_encryption_mode in a GAE app

Tags: mysql, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm running a GAE app in the Standard environment (thus, little control over things). It's using Cloud SQL for its backend (MySQL). How can I change the default `block_encryption_mode` on the database permanently to aes256? By default it's set to aes-128-ecb, which isn't good enough for our needs.

I've already looked at the available / configurable flags under Cloud SQL. `block_encryption_mode` isn't in the list. I'm surprised as 128-ecb is known to be weak. Is there any other way to change this in a Django app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `block_encryption_mode` isn't supported otherwise by Cloud SQL, one needs to set this per session (unfortunate, as it'll be an extra query over to the server with a slight performance hit, but no other way). To do this, set it as an `init_command` option for the database connection in your Django `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        "ENGINE": 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        "NAME": DB_NAME,
        "USER": DB_USER,
        "PASSWORD": ...,
        "PORT": ...,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "init_command": "SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc'",
        },
    }
}
```

This isn't directly related to the question, however changing block encryption mode to AES256 requires one to use an initialisation vector (IV), unique per encrypted content (otherwise the similarly of encrypted text can serve as a hint to a hacker).